# Hide element on all click events even when clicking on an element which has stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which I need to hide when clicking anywhere on the page, even on elements which have `e.stopPropagation()`.

I've tried

```
$(document).on("click",function(){
    $("#mydiv").hide();
});
```

Which works but doesn't work on an element which has the following:

```
$(document).on("click","#someDiv",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How can I make my element hide even on `#someDiv` without removing the `stopPropagation`. The reason I need this to be flexible is that I'm writing a plugin which anyone can use and will not know anything about the click events or element ids on the page.

Is there a way I can bind my hiding of an element to all clicks? Happy with a JS or jQuery solution.

I know it must be possible as I've seen other plugins do this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the quickest and most compatible solution with your existing code is to swap out the `#mydiv` hiding listener to use the vanilla JS [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) leveraging the `useCapture` optional third argument to grab the event before any inner elements have had a chance for their own listeners to fire.  See it in action in the snippet below:

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(){
    $("#mydiv").hide();
}, true);

$("#someDiv").on("click",function(e){
    console.log('some div clicked!');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: pink;
}

#mydiv {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#someDiv {
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="mydiv">Hide me!</div>
  <div id="someDiv">I'll stop propagation!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like adding an additional EventListener to all elements on your page by using

```
$('*').each( () => { 
 $(this).on("click", () => { 
  /* hide your div here */ 
 }) 
};
```